# Toggling a CSS class but disabling class from other elements after a new click

Tags: php, jquery, css

I've got thumbnails being generated dynamically from an array to toggle a background image for the page:

```
<?php
            for($i=0; $i < count($imageArray); $i++){
                 echo('<img onclick="changeBig(\''.$imageArray[$i].'\')" src="/lib/img/bkgr/'.$imageArray[$i].'" alt="thumbnail image" width="77" height="44" />');
            }
        ?>
```

I want to add a class of "current" to the thumbnail image when it is the selected/active background:

```
$('#bkgrSelector img').toggleClass(current, addOrRemove);
```

jQuery's toggleClass should do the trick, but I would want to clear the class off of previously clicked images when a new one is selected.

How fo I go about doing that?

Is there a better way via PHP or jQuery to toggle the current class on the image thumbnails?

The post-rendered bit from that PHP array is below, as requested:

```
<div id="bkgrSelector"> 
    <div class="scrollNav"> 
        <a class="prev"></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="scrollable">   
        <div class="items" id="thumbs"> 
            <img onclick="changeBig('Antipasti.jpg')" src="/lib/img/bkgr/Antipasti.jpg" alt="thumbnail image" width="77" height="44" />
```

> 

Comment: If you want to avoid a page reload, use JavaScript (or the jQuery library), if you don't mind a page reload then use php. Could you post the rendered html mark-up of your page (`view source`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the common `class` from all other images and then re-apply it to the one selected.

```
$('#bkgrSelector img').click(function(){
    $('#bkgrSelector img').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: While all three solutions are valid, this was the one I utilized.

Answer (score 1):

Have all the thumbnail images have a common class, such as `thumb`. You can then select all `thumb` images, and turn the `current` class off. Then turn it on for the selected one:

```
//make no thumb have the current class
$('img.thumb').removeClass('current');

//Add the class to your selected item
$selected.addClass('current');
```

You would need to add the `thumb` class in your loop:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($imageArray); $i++){
    echo('<img onclick="changeBig(\''.$imageArray[$i].'\')" src="/lib/img/bkgr/'.$imageArray[$i].'" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail image" width="77" height="44" />');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the class from existing images before adding it to the new one.

With jQuery

```
$("img").click( function() {
    //remove class from existing
    $("img.selected").removeClass('selected');
    //add class for current
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```